# Question closing policy

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, policy

I've just seen a question closed (for being vague and poorly worded) just **7 minutes** after being posted. Now, I feel it is quite bad to do so. That does not leave the time to the OP to understand what is wrong with it's question and improve it (and from the wording he seems to be a beginner and not an english native speaker).

I don't see the point on hurrying to close questions. Maybe someone can explain me the rationale behind this attitude ? For now it merely seems like being rude and hostile to beginners.

As a programmer I feel poor programs should be refactored and bugs should be corrected, not code dropped within minutes and asking questions does not seem that different.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the question.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284852/how-can-i-execute-c-program-under-another-one, and I agree it is not at all a good question and it probably deserve to be closed in it's current state. But the timing still bother me.

Answer (score 4):

@kriss - The question in the original state (and even after a couple of edits) deserved to be closed. Both because the question was meaningless junk contributing only noise to SO, AND as punishment to an annoying twerp who posted it with such an apparent lack of effort.

I personally do NOT feel that crappy obviously-no-efforts-put-into-it questions add ANY value to SO, nor do their posters, so i do NOT agree that this constitutes "beginner unfriendliness".

P.S. I really hate it when "not an English native speaker" is used as an excuse for laziness and total lack of effort, **especially in age of Google Translate**. Capitalizing the sentences is NOT a problem for non-native speakers - when you see the all-lower-case post, it's one of the surest ways to know no effort was put in. Lack of clear example and explanation of what the poster wants is also totally not related to English speaking.

As someone who's not an English native speaker, I totally resent this meme - it both promotes bad behavior AND is insulting to those non-native speakers who put in good effort into writing clear posts with some grammar issues - and so far I've yet to see a single case of a post like that being hated on (e.g. downvoted, closed or even negatively commented on) merely due to obvious non-native-language issues.

Comment: P.S. I voted to re-open since now after a gazillion edits the question is a lot less objectionable, though I fear it should be later re-closed as being a duplicate...

Comment: Is it really appropriate to call anyone an "annoying twerp"? http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2322696

Comment: @Lao - it's appropriate given the entire set of specific  circumstances. Though it's a bit insulting to all the twerps out there, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

That user has asked 43 questions now, many of which have been closed and/or received negative votes.

If the user in question still hasn't learned to [ask questions in a useful way](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), I don't think closing them quickly is particularly inappropriate. Maybe one day they'll get the message and put some effort into the questions... at which point they definitely won't get closed.

Comment: Jon - while I personally agree with the sentiment and sometimes follow the same logic, AFAIK the purely theoretical SO goal is to judge any post on only its own merits regardless of poster. Heck, I even voted to re-open this sorry excuse of a question now that a gazillion edits made it at least somewhat bearable :)

Comment: @DVK: I don't believe this question deserves to stay open when judged only on its merits. My point is that by now one might have expected the questioner to learn that such poor questions *will* get closed quickly. I have very little sympathy for the questioner here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm wondering if there is another way to let the repeat bad questioner know that closing a question=bad question. Clearly after 43 questions, they are failing to understand the rules. While you can blame them entirely for not reading the rules, I think that is unfair. People learn at different rates. It might be helpful for SO to trigger some kind of unavoidable post on their profile or within their notifications to help them understand in super simple english why their question wasn't good. Is that idea being talked about amongst SO leadership?

Comment: @timpeterson: I wouldn't know what's being talked about within "SO leadership", just being another user myself (not even a moderator). To be honest, I think there are already *plenty* of hints and suggestions. If someone is still posting bad questions after that long, I think it's *very* unlikely that they care about it, or that they've really put *any* effort into understanding why their questions are being closed/downvoted.

Comment: @JonSkeet fair enough, i guess schools fail students, so probably fair for SO to fail them too. thanks for your thoughts,